# How long does it take to run hlme in R run for large datasets?

Tags: r, statistics, runtime

I am doing groub based trajectory analysis using the hlme function from R package lcmm. My dataset is close to 800000 registrations, and I am using a cubic b-spline for the curve shape. It's running for a veeery long amount of time.

I left the analysis for 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 clusters to run through the weekend. On Monday morning it had completed 2 3 4 groups it was still running the 5, and Tuesday morning it is still running 5 groups. Is this something you'd expect? should i keep running it, or should i interrupt it, because something is propably wrong? My hardware is high-end with 64GB ddr5 and i9-13900K.